# Python async-generator not async

Tags: python, asynchronous, generator

My code is as follows. I want the two sleep can share the same time frame and take 1+2*3=7 seconds to run the script.
But it seems that something wrong happened so that it still takes 3*(1+2) second.

Is there any idea how to modify the code?

```py
import asyncio

async def g():
    for i in range(3):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        yield i

async def main():
    async for x in g():
        print(x)
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
res = loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

Comment: You are still running the ``sleep`` in ``g`` before yielding, and thus before the sleep in ``main``. The ``async``/``await`` syntax exists to do *multiple* tasks concurrently, not to do *one* task concurrently. You have only *one* task, so there is nothing that can run concurrently.

Comment: What is your *expected* outcome? Do you expect ``g`` to yield ``i`` before sleeping? Do you expect ``main`` to receive ``x`` while ``g`` sleeps? Do you expect ``g`` to prepare the next ``i`` while ``main`` sleeps?

Comment: I assume your ``sleep`` is some actual work in your real code? Is it computational or I/O?

Comment: Yes, I expect `g` to prepare the next `i` while `main` sleeps !
`sleep` is some actual work in my real code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The point of `async`/`await` is to interleave *tasks*, not functions/generators. For example, when you `await asyncio.sleep(1)`, your current coroutine is delayed along with the sleep. Similarly, an `async for` delays its coroutine until the next item is ready.

In order to run your separate functionality, you must create each part as a separate task. Use a `Queue` to exchange items between them - tasks will only be delayed until they have exchanged an item.

```
from asyncio import Queue, sleep, run, gather


# the original async generator
async def g():
    for i in range(3):
        await sleep(1)
        yield i


async def producer(queue: Queue):
    async for i in g():
        print('send', i)
        await queue.put(i)  # resume once item is fetched
    await queue.put(None)


async def consumer(queue: Queue):
    x = await queue.get()  # resume once item is fetched
    while x is not None:
        print('got', x)
        await sleep(2)
        x = await queue.get()


async def main():
    queue = Queue()
    # tasks only share the queue
    await gather(
        producer(queue),
        consumer(queue),
    )


run(main())
```

---

If you regularly need this functionality, you can also put it into a helper object that wraps an asynchronous iterable. The helper encapsulates the queue and separate task. You can apply the helper directly on an async iterable in an `async for` statement.

```
from asyncio import Queue, sleep, run, ensure_future


# helper to consume iterable as concurrent task
async def _enqueue_items(async_iterable, queue: Queue, sentinel):
    async for item in async_iterable:
        await queue.put(item)
    await queue.put(sentinel)


async def concurrent(async_iterable):
    """Concurrently fetch items from ``async_iterable``"""
    queue = Queue()
    sentinel = object()
    consumer = ensure_future(  # concurrently fetch items for the iterable
        _enqueue_items(async_iterable, queue, sentinel)
    )
    try:
        item = await queue.get()
        while item is not sentinel:
            yield item
            item = await queue.get()
    finally:
        consumer.cancel()


# the original generator
async def g():
    for i in range(3):
        await sleep(1)
        yield i


# the original main - modified with `concurrent`
async def main():
    async for x in concurrent(g()):
        print(x)
        await sleep(2)


run(main())
```

Comment: @cjs840312 Since this is a pattern that occurs regularly, I've now added an example helper that can be wrapped around existing async generators.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to doing this with a Queue, instead this solution chain Futures together, so that a Future's result is the current item and another Future to retrieve the next item (sort of like a linked list, so to speak):

```
from asyncio import sleep, get_event_loop, run, create_task

async def aiter(fut, async_generator):
    try:
        async for item in async_generator:
            fut, prev_fut = get_event_loop().create_future(), fut
            prev_fut.set_result((item, fut))
        else:
            fut.set_exception(StopAsyncIteration())
    except Exception as e:
        fut.set_exception(e)


async def concurrent(async_generator):
    fut = get_event_loop().create_future()
    create_task(aiter(fut, async_generator))

    try:
        while True:
            item, fut = await fut
            yield item
    except StopAsyncIteration as e:
        return
```

As an added bonus this solution will correctly handle exception that happens in g() by reraising the exception in the main() method with a traceback that will be useful for debugging.

Comment: Very nice because it guarantees a constant memory usage!